# Class variable in Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Lets say I have a "Student" model with functions `getActive()` and `getInactive()` like this:

```
public static function getActive()
{
    return Student::with(['user', 'country', 'course', 'gender', 'language' => function($q){$q->orderBy('name');}])->where('active', 1)->get();
}

public static function getInactive()
{
    return Student::with(['user', 'country', 'course', 'gender', 'language' => function($q){$q->orderBy('name');}])->where('active', 0)->get();
}
```

As you can see, the only difference is the `>where('active', 0)` at the end of each query.

I'm trying to declare a global "base query" to which I would append the `where` condition at the end. Something like this:

```
$baseQuery;

public function __construct()
{
    $baseQuery = Student::with(['user', 'country', 'course', 'gender', 'language' => function($q){$q->orderBy('name');}]);
}

public static function getActive()
{
    return $baseQuery->where('active', 1)->get();
}

public static function getInactive()
{
    return $baseQuery->where('active', 0)->get();
}
```

This would not only save me redundant code, it would also make my code more clear and visible but as a newbie I'm struggling with the code.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

I'm calling it like this from my controller:

```
$students = Profile::getActive();
```

Comment: How are you calling it in your code?

Comment: I edited my post with the answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Use [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
public function scopeRetrieve($query)
{
   return $query->with(['user', 'country', 'course', 'gender', 'language'])->orderBy('name');
}

public static function scopeActive($query)
{
   return $query->where('active', 1);
}

public static function scopeInactive()
{
  return $query->where('active', 0);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Profile::retrieve()->active()->get();
Profile::retrieve()->inactive()->get();
```

It encourages reusability since you're breaking them into chunks of its own, next time if you've more constraints or filter you could just add on to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereIn method.The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array:

```
public static function getInactiveOrInactive()
{
return Student::with(['user', 'country', 'course', 'gender', 'language' =>   function($q){$q->orderBy('name');}])->->whereIn('active', [0,1])->get();
}
```

Comment: Thats a good approach but I think its not the best one on this scenario since I have other methods that need this `$baseQuery`.